# Unable to access namespace or class when using import in Typescript

Tags: typescript

This is the code in file- app.ts

```
  import Express = require('express');
  import FileSystem = require('fs');
  import Http = require('http');

module Service {
    export interface Configuration {
        Port: number,
        Host: string
    }
    export class AppServer {
        App: Express.Application;
        AppServer: Http.Server;

        constructor() {
            this.App = Express();
            this.App.use(this.App.route);
            // this.App.use(this.App.router);

        }

        /**
         * Start the server
         * @param {Configuration} config
         */
        StartServer = function (config: Configuration) {
            var That = this;
            this.AppServer = this.App.listen(config.Port, function () {

                var Host = That.AppServer.address().address;
                var Port = That.AppServer.address().port;

                console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", Host, Port)

            })
        }
    }
}
```

when i am accessing the namespace in another file, i am getting the compile error that "unable to find service".

this is the code in file -server.ts

```
/// <reference path="App.ts" />

var Server = new Service.AppServer();
var Config = <Service.Configuration>{
    Port: 3000
}
Server.StartServer(Config);
```

but when i am removing the import statement which is requiring http and express, i am no more getting the error in the file.
Please help me to find- where i am doing wrong?

the error i am gettinf is - 'ts2304' can not find name 'service'.

Comment: Could you quote the error message?

Comment: As per error which service you are not able to find ? is it for your `Service` module or for `express`, `fs` or `http`?

Comment: I have updated the question,btw the error i am getting is- 'ts2304' can not find name 'Service'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have not exported the module. Try adding `export {Service}` at the end of your file.

Comment: After exporting, was the `Service` imported in server.ts. Something like this: `import {Service} from './app.ts'. ?`

Comment: I am trying to import like this -

import Service=Service; but i am getting the error - can not find service. But when i am doing like yours, i am no more getting the error.

Can you tell me, why my syntax is not working. But syntax is working when i m removing the require statement.

Comment: `import Service = require(./app.ts)` is used when a single object is exported from the module using `export = `. That might be the reason. Have a look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). Under  the section `export = and import = require()`, you will find your answer.